# SAS proc sql inside %macro

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

Firstly I have the following table:

```
data dataset;
    input id $ value;
    datalines;
    A 1
    A 2
    A 3
    A 4
    B 2
    B 3
    B 4
    B 5
    C 2
    C 4
    C 6
    C 8
    ;
run;
```

I would like to write a macro so that the user can subset the data by giving the id value. I do proc sql inside the macro as follows:

```
%macro sqlgrp(id=,);

proc sql;
        create table output_&id. as
        select *
        from dataset
        where id = '&id.'
        ;
    quit;
%mend;

%sqlgrp(id=A); /*select id=A only*/
```

I am able to generate the output_A table in the WORK library, however it has zero (0) observations.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use double quotes when referring to macro variables.

**Current Code**

```
%macro sqlgrp(id=,);

proc sql;
        create table output_&id. as
        select *
        from dataset
        where id = '&id.'
        ;
    quit;
%mend;

%sqlgrp(id=A); /*select id=A only*/
```

Looks for values of `id` that are *literally* '&id.'. You can test this by creating this dataset:

```
data dataset;
    input id $ value;
    datalines;
&id. 2
A    2
    ;
run;
```

Now, use `%let` to set the value of the macro variable `id`:

```
%let id=A;
```

Run a quick test of the functionality difference between single and double quotes. Notice the titles also contain single and double quotes, so we can see exactly what has happened in the output:

```
proc sql;
  title 'Single Quotes - where id=&id.';
  select *
  from dataset
  where id='&id.';

  title "Double Quotes - where id=&id.";
  select *
  from dataset
  where id="&id.";
  title;
quit;
```

**Correct Code**

```
%macro sqlgrp(id=,);

proc sql;
        create table output_&id. as
        select *
        from dataset
        where id = "&id."
        ;
    quit;
%mend;

%sqlgrp(id=A); /*select id=A only*/
```

The double quotes allow the macro variable &id to resolve to 'A', which will return results based on your input.

Comment: Thanks @mjsqu. thanks for clarify the difference between single quote and double quote. I have one question that is there any difference between &id. and &id (without the .) Thanks again.

Comment: Not really, in this case either will do. The period (.) tells SAS where the macro variable ends, and it is more often used when the macro variable is immediately followed by something else. Try running the following with and without the period (.): `%let id=A;%put &id._x;`

Comment: It would be probably useful to add input and output names to macro signature like %macro sqlgrp(in=, id=, out=) to avoid that users override the output

Comment: @Kostya - if you write an answer to that effect, I'll happily upvote it

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple rewrite of the previous answer which passes 'in' and 'out' through a signature of the macros

```
%macro sqlgrp(in=, id=, out=);
   proc sql noprint;
      create table &out. as select * from &in. where id = "&id.";
   quit;
%mend sqlgrp;
```