# error with quotes while passing macro variable to proc sql

Tags: sas-macro, proc-sql

I am trying to do following in macro:

```
proc sql;

select * from table1 where col1 like 'x%'

quit;


%macro temp(val=x);

proc sql;

select * from table1 where col1 like '&val%'

quit;

%mend;
```

The problem is that to resolve the value of val, it has to be in double quotes(" ") , but sql statement works only with single quotes(' '), as it throws the error with double quotes: Invalid column name.

Any suggestion how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the problem is either related to proc sql or quotes. 
Thus Proc Sql works perfectly with double quotes too. Also , Macro variable will not resolve under single quote.

My trial :

```
*1st attempt:* 
%macro test( x=feed);
proc sql;
create table test5 as
select * from files.spiderlist
where host like  "&x%";
quit;
%mend test;

*2nd attempt with || :*  
where host like  ("&x" || '%');
```

Both Return "feedly",
"feedfetcher", with 1st attempt slightly faster than the second attempt.

Comment: The proc sql statement with direct expression using double quotes doesn't work: Like select * from table1 where col1 like "x%", or infact col1="x", all throws the same error: Invalid column name.

Comment: Please take a look at the similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288623/sas-proc-sql-inside-macro